# Resource Allocation Graph: Two processes want the same resource

Tags: graphs, resource-allocation

In the example below, is this guaranteed to be safe? I see two processes that require the same resource. It's not a direct cycle but it seems to be a possible deadlock where P0 could get held up.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are these arrows supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the problem here?is there a missing edge from ur graph?....As I see it : R3 could be assigned to P1 till it finishes, then to P2 (or vice verca), finally when both P1 & P2 finishes P0 could get R1,R2 (freed by now)

Comment: My concern was that if one of the processes gets dead locked, like P1 on R3, then P2 will never get R3 and the whole thing gets dead locked.

Comment: If _something_ is deadlocked you don’t care whether other things get deadlocked. You fix the problem that caused the first deadlock. And one process can’t get deadlocked. It takes two. Actually it takes two or more processes each needing two or more resources.